# What exactly is "invalid syntax" and why do I keep getting it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying out this code but I keep running into a problem. I keep getting the message "invalid syntax" and it highlights "maracs" as the syntax error. I've substituted it with several nonexistent words and modified the code but it still gives me the same error. And yes, my variables are random words. Also, I really need the answer to be simple because I can barely understand all the information I find on this on the Internet.

```
start = input("On what day will you be leaving? (1 to 7 representing Monday to Sunday respectively.)"
maracs = input("How many days will your stay be?")
pooper = int(start) + int(maracs)
lob = pooper % 7
if lob = 0:
 print("You will arrive on Day 7 of the week of your arrival.")
else
 print("You will arrive on Day "lob "of the week of your arrival.")
```

Also, I'm having another problem. I keep getting "NameError" when I am trying this other code out. Please help define "NameError" in a simple way.

```
a = All
b = work
d = no
e = play
f = makes
g = Jack
h = a
i = dull
j = boy

print(a, b, "and", d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
```

Comment: Invalid syntax simply means that the code you have written cannot be interpreted as valid instructions for python. "Syntax" refers to the rules and structures of a language, normally spoken, but also in programming.

Comment: As a side note -- Whenever you get a `SyntaxError` on a line which looks just fine, it *usually* means that there is an unclosed parenthesis on the previous line.  This is because because python automatically joins lines until a closing parenthesis is found.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: I am pretty certain the OP understood that part. What's puzzling is that the reported line looks fine; because it's the preceding line that has the problem here.

Answer (score 9):

You forgot the closing parenthesis on the preceding line:

```
start = input("On what day will you be leaving? (1 to 7 representing Monday to Sunday respectively.)"
```

Note that there is no `)` *after* the closing quote. As python lets you join multiple lines together when using parenthesis, the parser doesn't know anything is wrong until the next line, where you get your SyntaxError because what followed there doesn't make sense.

As for you second example, you need to put quotes around your strings, `All` is not a string but a variable, and you didn't define `All`:

```
>>> a = All
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'All' is not defined
>>> a ='All'
>>> a
'All'
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the bracket (parenthesis) in the first line:

You have to end a function with a bracket. Like `input('something')`. What you did is: `input("On what day will you be leaving..."` <-- You forgot the closing parenthesis

```
start = input("On what day will you be leaving? (1 to 7 representing Monday to Sunday respectively.)")
```

Edit:
And you get the name error in second code because you are trying to print variables which have words. You need to put them in quotations like `" "` or `' '`. When you write them without the `" "` Python looks for a function/keyword with that name.
For e.g; `a = "All"`